# How to create multiple jquery functions with one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the below jquery functions which you can find in [this code pen](http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/xEVgok?editors=1010) that I would like to simplify.

I'd like to write the below javascript more concisely by writing a function that creates all the below functions, since the only difference are the following strings: name1, name2, name3, etc.

Javascript

```
$('#name1').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("name1").innerHTML = "name1";
    });
$('#name2').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("name2").innerHTML = "name2";
    });
$('#name3').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("name3").innerHTML = "name3";
    });
$('#name4').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("name4").innerHTML = "name4";
    });
$('#name5').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("name5").innerHTML = "name5";
    });
$('#name6').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("name6").innerHTML = "name6";
    });
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="name1">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name2">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name3">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name4">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name5">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name6">NAME</button>
```

Comment: Just give them all the same className...

Comment: @KevinB, I'm not sure it's a dup

Comment: @Dekel feel free to counter the close vote with a reopen if you're sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the simplest solution:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).html($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="name1">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name2">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name3">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name4">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name5">NAME</button>
<button type="button" id="name6">NAME</button>
```

If you want this to work on specific buttons you can use  `$('#name1,#name2,#name3...').on`.
If they all have specific class you can use `$('.specific-class').on`.
If they all exists inside some specific element you can use `$('div#id1 button').on`
And so on...

Comment: But what if document has other buttons? This solution is not necessarily general, but I am not an auto-downvoter so I won't downvote

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob, added a comment in the end of the answer. I also must say I don't really understand all the downvoters here...

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting every `button` on the page, so the selector can be simpler:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    //
});
```

And you're setting the "currently clicked element" to the value of its `id`, which can be more general:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    this.innerText = this.id;
});
```

Note: If this selector is *overly* simple (you don't want to target *every* `button` on the page), you can still use the original list of `id` values as a single selector.  Perhaps something like:

```
$('button[id^="name"]').on('click', function(){
    this.innerText = this.id;
});
```

Or even:

```
$('#name1, #name2, #name3, #name4, #name5, #name6').on('click', function(){
    this.innerText = this.id;
});
```

Sometimes it's also appropriate to assign click handlers to a single parent element, especially if there could be *many* matching elements.  Something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#name1, #name2, #name3, #name4, #name5, #name6', function(){
    this.innerText = this.id;
});
```

The difference here is that instead of assigning the handler function to *each* matching element, only one handler function is assigned to the `document` and the selector for the target `button` elements is evaluated on the fly when executing that handler.

Comment: Really? `$(this).html($(this).prop('id'));`? Much better as `this.innerHTML = this.id;`

Comment: `innerHTML` should not be used here. `textContent` because you're not altering the HTML.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Whatever it is, just this answer seems over jquery-fied

Comment: Fair enough, there are multiple ways to skin a cat.  Performance probably isn't a concern as much as consolidation in the original question, but either way.

Comment: Even better. no need for jquery @David ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Condense your jQuery to this:

```
$('button[id^="name"]').on('click', function(){
    var thisID = $(this).attr("id"),
        thisNum = thisID.replace("name", "");
    document.getElementById("name" + thisNum).innerHTML = "name" + thisNum;
});
```

An alternative, pure jQuery solution would be this:

```
$('button[id^="name"]').on('click', function(){
    var t       = $(this),
        thisID  = t.attr("id");

    t.html("name" + thisID.replace("name", ""));
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted, the only thing I'd change is the last line to `$(this).html('name ' + thisNum);`

Comment: @powerbuoy: I see your point - will add this as an alternative. I tried to answer in the spirit of what the OP already had.